# Can you take the dodge action multiple times on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, monk, dodge

The reason I ask this is that I'm doing a build focused on the Dwarven Fortitude feat.

> Whenever you take the Dodge action in combat, you can spend one Hit Die to heal yourself. Roll the die, add your Constitution modifier, and regain a number of hit points equal to the total (minimum of 1).

The Dodge Action

> When you take the Dodge action, you focus entirely on avoiding attacks. Until the start of your next turn, any attack roll made against you has disadvantage if you can see the attacker, and you make Dexterity saving throws with advantage. You lose this benefit if you are incapacitated or if your speed drops to O.

I know that normally you can't because you only have one action per turn, but I plan on going into monk for other reasons. I know that taking the Dodge action twice does not give attackers double disadvantage, I'm mostly hoping that I can benefit Dwarven Fortitude multiple times to be a pretty good tank when in combination with a Moon Druid.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Yes, you can

The text you cite is the entire rules text for the Dodge action (p. 192, *PHB*). There is nothing other than the available number of actions that would limit the Dodge action. No rule states that you can dodge only once per turn. This is not different from taking multiple Attack or Dash actions, which is done more often.

Features that would allow you to take multiple Dodge actions in a turn are for example the fighter's Action surge or the monk's Patient Defense feature that lets you Dodge as a bonus action.

Under normal circumstances, this would not have *any* benefit, because advantage and disadvantage do not stack, so using multiple actions to dodge would be entirely wasteful. With Dwarven Fortitude, it will allow you to take as many hit die, as you can take dodge actions, as long as you have unused hit die remaining.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if there were more rules on it because I often find googling it is unreliable, and I didn't want to look through hundreds of pages of rules.

Comment: "With Dwarven Fortitude, it will allow you to take as many hit die, as you can take dodge actions." or as many as you have HD to spend, whichever is fewer.  You might point out that this is, in terms of rules permissiveness, no different front taking two Dashes, or two Attack actions, both of which are done all the time.  The only difference (as you do point out) is that absent the interaction with Fortitude, there is no inherent benefit to Dodging twice.

Comment: @Kirt, Good points, addded.

Comment: @Nobody-the-Hobgoblin I'm playing in a pretty heavily homebrew campaign that messes with action economy. The short of it is that it is similar to the Pathfinder system so taking an action for something like this isn't as big of a deal. Not to mention that the Dodge action also gives creatures that you can see and who are attacking you disadvantage, so it isn't just healing. I'm also not using my hit dice because I am going to be going into wildshape, which gives you the creature's hit dice. It's like I have two health pools, and passive regeneration. Talk about a tank!

Comment: @defmod: Yes, the dodge action is very good, also gives advantage on Dex saves.  The thing that's normally useless is spending more than one action or bonus action on it in a turn, since it doesn't stack.  Normally I'd say do something else useful with your action or bonus and only heal one HD per round, since you'll run out soon, but if you can spend HD from wildshape forms then yeah there's some use-it-or-lose-it aspect to making use of that resource as well as actions.

Comment: @defmod: One extra hit die is still not much healing vs. the  benefit you normally get from an Attack action or even cantrip, but in wild shape some beasts may have weaker attacks, and maybe two HD instead of one is the difference between healing enough to survive one more hit or not.  But if you're not being a threat, enemies will ignore you and attack your friends instead, unless you're blocking a hallway or something.